# Convert HTML to data:text/html  link using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, url, base64, data-uri

Here's my HTML:

```
<a>View it in your browser</a>
<div id="html">
    <h1>Doggies</h1>
    <p style="color:blue;">Kitties</p>
</div>
```

How do I use JavaScript to make the `href` attribute of my link point to a base64 encoded webpage whose source is the `innerHTML` of `div#html`?

I basically want to do the same conversion done [here](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data) (with the base64 checkbox checked) except for in JavaScript.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Characteristics of a data-URI

A [data-URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) with MIME-type `text/html` has to be in one of these formats:

```
data:text/html,<HTML HERE>
data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,<HTML HERE>
```

Base-64 encoding is not necessary. If your code contains non-ASCII characters, such as `éé`, `charset=UTF-8` has to be added.

The following characters have to be escaped:

- `#` - Firefox and Opera interpret this character as the marker of a hash (as in `location.hash`).
- `%` - This character is used to escape characters. Escape this character to make sure that no side effects occur.

Additionally, if you want to embed the code in an anchor tag, the following characters should also be escaped:

- `" and/or '` - Quotes mark the value of the attribute.
- `&` - The ampersand is used to mark HTML entities.
- `<` and `>` do **not have to** be escaped **inside a HTML attribute**. However, if you're going to embed the link in the HTML, these should also be escaped (`%3C and %3E`)

#### JavaScript implementation

If you don't mind the size of the data-URI, the easiest method to do so is using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
var html = document.getElementById("html").innerHTML;
var dataURI = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
```

If size matters, you'd better strip out all consecutive white-space (this can safely be done, unless the HTML contains a `<pre>` element/[style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space#Values)). Then, only replace the significant characters:

```
var html = document.getElementById("html").innerHTML;
html = html.replace(/\s{2,}/g, '')   // <-- Replace all consecutive spaces, 2+
           .replace(/%/g, '%25')     // <-- Escape %
           .replace(/&/g, '%26')     // <-- Escape &
           .replace(/#/g, '%23')     // <-- Escape #
           .replace(/"/g, '%22')     // <-- Escape "
           .replace(/'/g, '%27');    // <-- Escape ' (to be 100% safe)
var dataURI = 'data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,' + html;
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. This was really helpful! :)

Comment: Note Opera behaves similarly to Firefox regarding `#`. Chrome and Safari do not attach a special meaning to `#`.

Comment: Small typo in the example at the bottom. If I'm not mistaken, `data:text/html,charset=UTF-8` should be `data:text/html;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @B1KMusic Thanks for bringing it up. The comma must indeed be changed to a semicolon, and a trailing semicolon need to be added. Revised answer.

Comment: Would [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) work instead of your many uses of the `replace` method?

Comment: @Web_Designer Yes. That's stated in the section before the code block with the many `.replace`s.

Comment: Don't you need to loop on 'Replace all consecutive spaces' multiple times? Original: ssssss. 1st pass: sss. 2nd pass: ss. 3rd pass: s.

Answer (score 0):

If size matters, you'd better strip out all consecutive white-space (this can safely be done, unless the HTML contains a `<pre>` element/style). Then, only replace the significant characters: