# Exporting the DOM's current styles

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, export, computed-style

Is there a JavaScript DOM API to get the current style information (selectors and their associated CSS rules, width and height attributes, style attributes, etc.) for a node or set of nodes and save them into an XML document or similar?

I want to do automated comparison tests.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm guessing this is about JavaScript? Please add that tag/information

Comment: Are you asking about HTML document object model? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following methods:

- [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML)
- [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html#serializedom)
- [e4x.js](https://github.com/eligrey/e4x.js)
- [DataURI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238890/)

Comment: I'm not sure how these help? Am I missing some XML that would give me access to all the properties I need?

Comment: These are JavaScript functions which collect the nodes of the XML DOM and return a single string. The XPath statement `$x("//*")` can perform a similar operation from the browser console.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this is not what I'm after. It just returns the HTML. I want all the properties of each of the elements in the HTML/DOM.

I've since found these:
`getComputedStyle()`
`dom.currentStyle`
`dom.style`

These can get me all the style information - which is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Style and state are very different, so please rephrase your question.