# How to create a Web Worker from a string

Tags: javascript, web-worker, data-uri

How can I use create a Web worker from a string (which is supplied via a POST request)?

One way I can think of, but I'm not sure how to implement it, is by creating a data-URI from the server response, and passing that to the Worker constructor, but I've heard that some browsers don't allow this, because of the same origin policy.

[MDN states the uncertainty about the origin policy around data URI's](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers):

> Note: The URI passed as parameter of the Worker constructor must obey the same-origin  policy. There is currently disagreement among browsers vendors on whether data URIs are of the same-origin or not; Gecko 10.0 (Firefox 10.0 / Thunderbird 10.0) and later do allow data URIs as a valid script for workers. Other browsers may disagree.

Here's also a post [discussing it on the whatwg](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-March/030878.html).

Comment: I wonder if CORS (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors) would help. HTMl5rocks uses strong "must" language when it comes to same origin policy for workers (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics) so maybe CORS is not of much help here. Did you try it though?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

> #### Summary
>
> - `blob:` for Chrome 8+, Firefox 6+, Safari 6.0+, Opera 15+
> - `data:application/javascript` for Opera 10.60 - 12
> - `eval` otherwise (IE 10+)

[`URL.createObjectURL(<Blob blob>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) can be used to create a Web worker from a string. The blob can be created using the [`BlobBuilder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder) API <sup>deprecated</sup> or the [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob#Blob_constructor_example_usage).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcFM/49/

```
// URL.createObjectURL
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

// "Server response", used in all examples
var response = "self.onmessage=function(e){postMessage('Worker: '+e.data);}";

var blob;
try {
    blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/javascript'});
} catch (e) { // Backwards-compatibility
    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
    blob = new BlobBuilder();
    blob.append(response);
    blob = blob.getBlob();
}
var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

// Test, used in all examples:
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert('Response: ' + e.data);
};
worker.postMessage('Test');
```

### Compatibility

Web workers are supported in the following browsers <sup>[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers#Browser_compatibility)</sup>:

- Chrome 3
- Firefox 3.5
- IE 10
- Opera 10.60
- Safari 4

This method's support is based on the support of the `Blob` API and the `URL.createObjectUrl` method. [`Blob` compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder#Browser_compatibility):

- Chrome 8+ (`WebKitBlobBuilder`), 20+ (`Blob` constructor)
- Firefox 6+ (`MozBlobBuilder`), 13+ (`Blob` constructor)
- Safari 6+ (`Blob` constructor)

IE10 supports `MSBlobBuilder` and `URL.createObjectURL`. However, trying to create a Web Worker from a `blob:`-URL throws a SecurityError.

Opera 12 does not support `URL` API. Some users may have a fake version of the `URL` object, thanks to [this hack in `browser.js`](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1589432&t=1367917090&page=1#comment13564572).

### Fallback 1: data-URI

Opera supports data-URIs as an argument to the `Worker` constructor. Note: Do not forget to [escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239272/938089?convert-html-to-datatext-html-link-using-javascript) (Such as `#` and `%`).

```
// response as defined in the first example
var worker = new Worker('data:application/javascript,' +
                        encodeURIComponent(response) );
// ... Test as defined in the first example
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcFM/37/

### Fallback 2: Eval

`eval` can be used as a fallback for Safari (<6) and IE 10.

```
// Worker-helper.js
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    self.onmessage = null; // Clean-up
    eval(e.data);
};
// Usage:
var worker = new Worker('Worker-helper.js');
// `response` as defined in the first example
worker.postMessage(response);
// .. Test as defined in the first example
```

Comment: @BrianFreid Thanks for your edit, but it's not needed. If you look a few lines further, you'll see "IE10 supports `MSBlobBuilder` and `URL.createObjectURL`. However, trying to create a Web Worker from a `blob:`-URL throws a SecurityError.". So, adding `MSBlobBuilder` will have no effect, the only option is fallback #2.

Comment: Opera 12 no longer defines `URL` (and hence neither defines any properties on it), and the Blob constructor is nowadays well enough supported.

Comment: I have verified that this still happens in IE11, at least in the preview.

Comment: Are dataURIs supported only in Opera or in all other browsers (except IE) as well?

Comment: Also new Function maybe more performative than eval (at least it is - in non-IE browsers).

Comment: @jayarjo `data:`-URIs for Web Workers are also supported in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Opera 15+. The performance of `eval` is not relevant, you're not going to create millions of Web workers per second.

Comment: self.close() and worker.terminate() kill IE11 - '`Discontinued operation of the program "Internet Explorer"`.     How to get around a bug?

Comment: is there a way to do it with Blob in IE 10?

Comment: @MatjažJurečič AFAIK, no.

Comment: I would just love it, if Microsoft would drop dead!

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming that window.URL is set, but never used? (only "URL" is used)

Answer (score 19):

I agree with the current accepted answer but often editing and managing the worker code will be hectic as its in the form of a string.

So optionally we can use the below approach where we can keep the worker as a function, and then covert to string->blob:

```
// function to be your worker
function workerFunction() {
    var self = this;
    self.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('Received input: ', e.data); // message received from main thread
        self.postMessage("Response back to main thread");
    }
}


///////////////////////////////

var dataObj = '(' + workerFunction + ')();'; // here is the trick to convert the above fucntion to string
var blob = new Blob([dataObj.replace('"use strict";', '')]); // firefox adds "use strict"; to any function which might block worker execution so knock it off

var blobURL = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob, {
    type: 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8'
});


var worker = new Worker(blobURL); // spawn new worker

worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Worker said: ', e.data); // message received from worker
};
worker.postMessage("some input to worker"); // Send data to our worker.
```

This is tested in IE11+ and FF and Chrome

Comment: @SenJacob As this is not a community wiki post, you should expose potential issues to the poster via a comment instead of an edit.

Comment: @FrankerZ Sorry. I had to make it work in IE11 with the changes I did.
@ ChanuSukarno Could you please check whether the changes in the [revision 3](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37156020/revisions) is OK?

Comment: FYI, the "type: 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8'" belongs in the Blob constructor, not the createObjectURL call.

Comment: So... You're building a function outside of your worker, just to simply read it better in your text editor? That's ridiculous. You have to load that function into memory in two contexts for no reason.

Comment: How can you use this, but passing parameters into the function `workerFunction` to use to generate the code with?

Comment: @ADJenks. For me loading function into two contexts is not expensive (compared to all the other stuff my app does).  Sometimes I want to run my worker function in foreground (e.g. for synchronous return) so I will often need to load my function in two contexts anyway.  Also, the trick to stringily function works through TypeScript and WebPack processing which is a big win for me.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is a bit complex, due to supporting backwards compatibility, so I wanted to post the same thing but simplified. Try this in your (modern) browser console:

```js
const code = "console.log('Hello from web worker!')"
const blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'application/javascript'})
const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
// See the output in your console.
```

Answer (score 4):

I've made an approach with most of your ideas and adding some of mine. The only thing my code needs on worker is to use 'this' to refer 'self' scope. I'm pretty sure that this is very improvable:

```
// Sample code
var code = function() {
    this.onmessage = function(e) {
        this.postMessage('Worker: '+e.data);
        this.postMessage('Worker2: '+e.data);
    };
};

// New thread worker code
FakeWorkerCode = function(code, worker) {
    code.call(this);
    this.worker = worker;
}
FakeWorkerCode.prototype.postMessage = function(e) {
    this.worker.onmessage({data: e});
}
// Main thread worker side
FakeWorker = function(code) {
    this.code = new FakeWorkerCode(code, this);
}
FakeWorker.prototype.postMessage = function(e) {
    this.code.onmessage({data: e});
}

// Utilities for generating workers
Utils = {
    stringifyFunction: function(func) {
        // Stringify the code
        return '(' + func + ').call(self);';
    },
    generateWorker: function(code) {
        // URL.createObjectURL
        windowURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;   
        var blob, worker;
        var stringified = Utils.stringifyFunction(code);
        try {
            blob = new Blob([stringified], {type: 'application/javascript'});
        } catch (e) { // Backwards-compatibility
            window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
            blob = new BlobBuilder();
            blob.append(stringified);
            blob = blob.getBlob();
        }

        if ("Worker" in window) {
            worker = new Worker(windowURL.createObjectURL(blob));
        } else {
            worker = new FakeWorker(code);
        }
        return worker;
    }
};

// Generate worker
var worker = Utils.generateWorker(code);
// Test, used in all examples:
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert('Response: ' + e.data);
};
function runWorker() {
    worker.postMessage('working fine');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8N6aR/

Answer (score 2):

Nice answer - I've been working on a similar problem today when trying to create Web Workers with fallback capabilities when they're not available (i.e. run worker script in main thread). As this thread is pertains to the topic, I thought I'd provide my solution here:

```
    <script type="javascript/worker">
        //WORKER FUNCTIONS
        self.onmessage = function(event) {
            postMessage('Hello, ' + event.data.name + '!');
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function inlineWorker(parts, params, callback) {

            var URL = (window.URL || window.webkitURL);

            if (!URL && window.Worker) {

                var worker = new window.Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([parts], { "type" : "text/javascript" })));

                worker.onmessage = function(event) {
                  callback(event.data);
                };

                worker.postMessage(params);

            } else {

                var postMessage = function(result) {
                  callback(result);
                };

                var self = {}; //'self' in scope of inlineWorker. 
                eval(parts); //Converts self.onmessage function string to function on self via nearest scope (previous line) - please email chrisgwgreen.site@gmail.com if this could be tidier.
                self.onmessage({ 
                    data: params 
                });
            }
        }

        inlineWorker(
            document.querySelector('[type="javascript/worker"]').textContent, 
            {
                name: 'Chaps!!'
            },
            function(result) {
                document.body.innerHTML = result;
            }
        );

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Chanu_Sukarno's code, you can simply pass in a worker function (or string) to this function and it will execute it inside a web worker:

```
async function doWorkerTask(workerFunction, input, buffers) {
  // Create worker
  let fnString = '(' + workerFunction.toString().replace('"use strict";', '') + ')();';
  let workerBlob = new Blob([fnString]);
  let workerBlobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(workerBlob, { type: 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8' });
  let worker = new Worker(workerBlobURL);

  // Run worker
  return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    worker.onmessage = function(e) { resolve(e.data); };
    worker.postMessage(input, buffers);
  });
}
```

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
function myTask() {
  self.onmessage = function(e) {
    // do stuff with `e.data`, then:
    self.postMessage("my response");
    self.close();
  }
}
let output = await doWorkerTask(myTask, input, inputBuffers);
// now you can do something with `output` (which will be equal to "my response")
```

---

---

In **nodejs**, `doWorkerTask` looks like this:

```
async function doWorkerTask(workerFunction, input, buffers) {
  let Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
  let worker = new Worker(workerFunction);

  // Run worker
  return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    worker.onmessage = function(e) { resolve(e.data); };
    worker.postMessage(input, buffers);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach that lets you define a worker using a function with optional setup arguments.

note - you can only use setup arguments that can be stringified - use worker.postMessage to send anything else

```js
// define our worker function
function workerFunc(arg1,arg2) {
  console.log("worker is running:"+arg1+" "+arg2);    
  
  postMessage(arg1+" "+arg2);
  
  setInterval(sendTime,1000);
  
  function sendTime(){
    postMessage(new Date().toUTCString() );
  }

  
}



// (optionally) define an element to inspect the script that worker will use
workerFunc.debug = document.getElementById("worker_script");

// start the worker and get replies from it
startWorker(workerFunc,"hello","world").addEventListener("message",function(e){
   document.getElementById("worker_reply").innerHTML = e.data;  
});



function startWorker (fn) {
    const src  = fn.toString();
    const args = src.substring(src.indexOf("(")+1,src.indexOf(")"));
    const code = ( args ?  "let ["+args+"]="+JSON.stringify([].slice.call(arguments,1))+";\n"  : "" )+ src.substring(src.indexOf("{")+1,src.length-1);
    const blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'application/javascript'})
    if (fn.debug) fn.debug.innerHTML=code;
    return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
}
```

```html
<textarea id="worker_reply"></textarea>

<h1>Worker Script</h1>
<pre id="worker_script">
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my tiny plugin https://github.com/zevero/worker-create

```
var worker_url = Worker.create("self.postMessage('Example post from Worker');");
var worker = new Worker(worker_url);
```

But you may also give it a function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you can use something like

> **[task.js](https://github.com/icodeforlove/task.js)** Simplified interface for getting CPU intensive code to run on all cores (node.js, and web)

A example would be

```
// turn blocking pure function into a worker task
const functionFromPostRequest = task.wrap('function (exampleArgument) {}');

// run task on a autoscaling worker pool
functionFromPostRequest('exampleArgumentValue').then(result => {
    // do something with result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution (can be "promise"d easily...)

```
   function makeWorker(workerFunction, cb) {
        // Create worker
        var tplFun = "onmessage = function(e){console.log(e);   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.data); var res=___.apply(this,args);postMessage(res);}"
        var fnTxt = workerFunction.toString().replace('"use strict";', '');
        var final = tplFun.replace("___", fnTxt);
        let workerBlob = new Blob([final]);
        let workerBlobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(workerBlob, { type: 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8' });
        let worker = new Worker(workerBlobURL);
        return function () {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            console.log(args)
            worker.postMessage(args);
            worker.onmessage = function (e) {
                console.log(e.data);
                cb(e.data);
            }
        }
    }

    function myTask(a, b, c) {
        return a * b * c;
    }

    function onresult(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    var fn = makeWorker(myTask, onresult)
    fn(1, 2, 3);
```

Can be nice with "pure and slow" function !

Answer (score 0):

Based on accepted answer, class to worker, interesting topic

```js
// worker class
class SimpleWorker {

    constructor() {
        console.log("simple worker init");
    }

    onMessage(event) {
        console.log("main to worker", event.data);

        postMessage({
            type: "answer", 
            data: "data from worker"
        });

    }

}

// class to worker
const workerFromClass = workerClassRef => {

    console.log(workerClassRef.name, "to worker");

    // factory method, converted to string, used to instanciate worker
    let workerFactory = (self, workerClass) => {

        let worker = new workerClass();
        self["onmessage"] = worker.onMessage.bind(worker);

    };

    // compute worker code string
    // worker class & factory function
    let str = workerClassRef.toString() + "\n"
        + "(" + workerFactory.toString() + ")" 
        + "(this," + workerClassRef.name + ");"
        
    // worker code to blob
    let blob = new Blob(
        [str], 
        {type: "application/javascript"}
    );
        
    // return worker instance
    return new Worker(
        URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    );

};

// main
// create worker
let worker = workerFromClass(SimpleWorker);

// handle messages from worker
worker.addEventListener(
    "message", 
    event => console.log("worker to main", event.data)
);

// send message to worker
let message = {
    type: "question", 
    data: "data from main"
};
console.log("main to worker", message);
worker.postMessage(message);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get real-data from the *objectURL* and not just blob by changing the `responseType` to either `"text"` or `"arraybuffer"`.

Here is a *back-and-forth conversion* of `text/javascript` to `blob` to `objectURL` back to `blob` or `text/javascript`.

<sub>*if you are wondering, I'm using it to generate a **web-worker with no external files*** 

*you may use it to return binary content, for example a YouTube video ;) (from the <video> tag resource attribute)*</sub>

```
var blob = new Blob(['self.onmessage=function(e){postMessage(e)}'],{type: 'text/javascript'});   //->console: (object)   Blob {size: 42, type: "text/javascript", slice: function}

var obju = URL.createObjectURL(js_blob); //->console:  "blob:http%3A//stackoverflow.com/02e79c2b-025a-4293-be0f-f121dd57ccf7"

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'blob:http%3A//stackoverflow.com/02e79c2b-025a-4293-be0f-f121dd57ccf7', true);
xhr.responseType = 'text'; /* or "blob" */
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.DONE !== xhr.readyState) return;

  console.log(xhr.response);
}
xhr.send();

/*
  responseType "blob" ->console: (object)   Blob {size: 42, type: "text/javascript", slice: function}
  responseType "text" ->console: (text)     'self.onmessage=function(e){postMessage(e)}'
*/
```