# Unable to use worker_threads in electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, web-worker, worker

With [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) boilerplate I generated electron application. Then I changed its electron version to `4.2.1` which ship node in version `10.11.0`.

Then I try to use worker_threads module. First I tried like this:

```
const Worker = require('worker_threads');
new Worker('./workerDummy.js');
```

but it says Worker is not a costructor so I consoled.log it:

```
{ isMainThread: true,
MessagePort:
 { [Function: MessagePort]
   super_:
    { [Function: EventEmitter]
      EventEmitter: [Circular],
      usingDomains: false,
      defaultMaxListeners: [Getter/Setter],
      init: [Function],
      listenerCount: [Function] } },
MessageChannel: [Function: MessageChannel],
threadId: 0,
Worker: [Function: Worker],
parentPort: null }
```

[NodeJS docs about worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/worker_threads.html) is giving example with just `new Worker(path)` but I assume it's other version or something and I should use Worker.Worker as I see `.Worker` is a function. So I changed it to:

```
new Worker.Worker('./workerDummy.js');
```

and now application just crash without any error info.

I've created [demo repository](https://github.com/BorysTyminski/electron-worker-issue). Steps to reproduce:

- git clone https://github.com/BorysTyminski/electron-worker-issue.git

  - cd path/where/you/cloned
  - npm install
  - npm run dev
  - click "Start NodeJS button"

creating NodeJS worker is in '@/src/main/index.js'.

---

I had some issues with electron-vue boilerplate before (for example I can not make it work with lates electron 5.x) so I wanted to check with some other boilerplate which is much more "pure" like electron-forge CLI which is recommended to use even in electron docs. So I generated fresh project with

```
npm i -g @electron-forge/cli
electron-forge init with-forge-cli --template=webpack
```

It has latest electron version `5.0.2` which ships node v12.x so it's fine. Then in main.js I added

```
const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');
```

and below in app.on ready:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    createWindow();
    new Worker('./workerDummy.js');
});
```

behavior is exacly same so I doubt it's because of electron-vue.

---

I believe it's not usage error but electron bug so I posted [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18540) on electron github.

Comment: Could it somehow be related to the Chrome bug? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22719772/10364842