# JavaScript File Hash Value Generate with Part of the file

Tags: javascript, php, hash, md5, cryptojs

I am working with JavaScript to generate File HASH VALUE for unique file values. Kindly check the below code for the Hash Generation Mechanism Which works good.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Reference: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#MD5
function handleFileSelect(evt) 
{   
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) 
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) 
        {
            return function(e) 
            {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                var test = e.target.result;                 
                //var hash = hex_md5(test);
                var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(test);
                var elem = document.getElementById("hashValue");
                elem.value = hash;
            };
        })(f);
        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
}
document.getElementById('videoupload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

However I am facing problem when generating HASH VALUE for large files as in client side the browser Crashed.

Up-till 30MB the HASHING works well but if i try to upload larger than that the system crashes.

**My Question is:**

> 1. Can I generate HASH Value for part of file than reading the LARGE files and getting crashes? If yes, Can I know how to do that width
>      'FileReader';
> 2. Can I specify any amount of Byte such as 2000 Character of a file to generate HASH Value then generating for large files.

I hope the above two solution will work for larger and small files. Is there any other options?

[My Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ea091939/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Can I generate HASH Value for part of file than reading the LARGE files and getting crashes? If yes, Can I know how to do that width 'FileReader';

Yes, you can do that and it is called [Progressive Hashing](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Progressive_Hashing).

```
var md5 = CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create();

md5.update("file part 1");
md5.update("file part 2");
md5.update("file part 3");

var hash = md5.finalize();
```

> 2. Can I specify any amount of Byte such as 2000 Character of a file to generate HASH Value then generating for large files.

There's an [HTML5Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files) on how one can use [`File.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.slice) to pass a sliced file to the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

```
var blob = file.slice(startingByte, endindByte);
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

### Full solution

I have combined both. The tricky part was to synchronize the file reading, because [`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) is asynchronous. I've written a small `series` function which is modeled after the [`series` function of async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback). It has to be done one after the other, because there is is no way to get to the internal state of the hashing function of CryptoJS.

Additionally, CryptoJS doesn't understand what an `ArrayBuffer` is, so it has to be converted to its native data representation, which is the so-called WordArray:

```
function arrayBufferToWordArray(ab) {
  var i8a = new Uint8Array(ab);
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) {
    a.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]);
  }
  return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(a, i8a.length);
}
```

The other thing is that hashing is a synchronous operation where there is no `yield` to continue execution elsewhere. Because of this, the browser will freeze since JavaScript is single threaded. The solution is to use [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) to off-load the hashing to a different thread so that the UI thread keeps responsive.
Web workers expect the script file in their constructors, so I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372280) by Rob W to have an inline script.

```
function series(tasks, done){
    if(!tasks || tasks.length === 0) {
        done();
    } else {
        tasks[0](function(){
            series(tasks.slice(1), done);
        });
    }
}

function webWorkerOnMessage(e){
    if (e.data.type === "create") {
        md5 = CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create();
        postMessage({type: "create"});
    } else if (e.data.type === "update") {
        function arrayBufferToWordArray(ab) {
            var i8a = new Uint8Array(ab);
            var a = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) {
                a.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]);
            }
            return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(a, i8a.length);
        }
        md5.update(arrayBufferToWordArray(e.data.chunk));
        postMessage({type: "update"});
    } else if (e.data.type === "finish") {
        postMessage({type: "finish", hash: ""+md5.finalize()});
    }
}

// URL.createObjectURL
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

// "Server response", used in all examples
var response = 
    "importScripts('https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js');"+
    "var md5;"+
    "self.onmessage = "+webWorkerOnMessage.toString();

var blob;
try {
    blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/javascript'});
} catch (e) { // Backwards-compatibility
    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
    blob = new BlobBuilder();
    blob.append(response);
    blob = blob.getBlob();
}
var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));


var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object    
var chunksize = 1000000; // the chunk size doesn't make a difference
var i = 0, 
    f = files[i],
    chunks = Math.ceil(f.size / chunksize),
    chunkTasks = [],
    startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    // create callback

    for(var j = 0; j < chunks; j++){
        (function(j, f){
            chunkTasks.push(function(next){
                var blob = f.slice(j * chunksize, Math.min((j+1) * chunksize, f.size));
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var chunk = e.target.result;
                    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
                        // update callback
                        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = ""+(j+1)+"/"+chunks;
                        next();
                    };
                    worker.postMessage({type: "update", chunk: chunk});
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
            });
        })(j, f);
    }
    series(chunkTasks, function(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("hashValueSplit");
        var telem = document.getElementById("time");
        worker.onmessage = function(e) {
            // finish callback
            elem.value = e.data.hash;
            telem.innerHTML = "in " + Math.ceil(((new Date()).getTime() - startTime) / 1000) + " seconds";
        };
        worker.postMessage({type: "finish"});
    });

    // blocking way ahead...
    if (document.getElementById("singleHash").checked) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onloadend = (function(theFile) {
            function arrayBufferToWordArray(ab) {
                var i8a = new Uint8Array(ab);
                var a = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) {
                    a.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]);
                }
                return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(a, i8a.length);
            }
            return function(e) {
                var test = e.target.result;
                var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(arrayBufferToWordArray(test));
                //var hash = "none";
                var elem = document.getElementById("hashValue");
                elem.value = hash;
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    }
};
worker.postMessage({type: "create"});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/artjomb/g389tpdf/) seems to work for big files, but it takes quite a lot of time. Maybe this can be improved using a faster MD5 implementation. It took around 23 minutes to hash a 3 GB file.

[This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33918579/1816580) shows an example without webworkers for SHA-256.

Comment: Artjom how can I make the file split? How i can split the videos?

Comment: Thats the difficult part which i dont know to split large video files of 1-3 GB :(

Comment: Artjom I have added your code to my function but it keeps on generating the same hash.. for all files. md5.update("file part 1");? what is this actuall means?

Comment: is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @Musa That was indeed it.

Comment: @TomPHP It works. See fiddle and updated answer. Let's clean up the comments.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have checked your code and still for me it crashes may be because of my browser :( but i am trying to modify your code such as not to run the FULL Split i just use the first 2 SPLIT and break the Logic and create a hash from the 2 SPLIT. But I am again struck up because CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create() shoots me an error "The length is not specified".

Comment: @ArtjomB. because the CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create() still thinks the @ SPLIT as a file and reads it as FILE so the error occurs i think? I am not expert i think :( .. So can you help me in hashing the 2 SPLITS and stop the split so the time and memory might be saved. Thank you..

Comment: @TomPHP I changed the implementation so that web workers are used. It works really well, but might need a faster implementation of MD5.

Comment: @ArtjomB. But Can we stop the chunk just for 2 not running all splits?

Comment: @TomPHP Why would you do that?

Comment: @TomPHP But then you won't hash the complete file which makes the hashing of the first two chunks useless. If not the complete file is hashed, you won't detect data corruption when it happens in the un-hashed parts of the file. Maybe you mean that the chunk size has to be increased so that fewer file reads are necessary and only two hash updates are needed? If so, this won't get you much, because hashing is the slower operation of the two, not the file reading. It would take the same time and may not work for bigger files.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Can you guide me to do that.. I will try with min 4-6 Chunks and hash the files.. Because as per the business logic i am in I just need part of the files to get Hash.. I dont need full length to be done.. Any comments?

Comment: @TomPHP That wasn't part of your question, but I guess you could change `for(var j = 0; j < chunks; j++){` to `for(var j = 0; j < 6; j++){`. Then you would have to tell the server how much of the file has to be hashed to get the same result.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have added in question "Can I specify any amount of Byte such as 2000 Character of a file to generate HASH Value then generating for large files." I mentioned Byte there.. I will try the last solution..

Comment: @TomPHP I see, that is what you meant. But then your question doesn't make sense anymore. Why would you need progressive hashing when you need only 2 KB hashed and up to 30 MB worked already. Your question should have been: "How do I hash only a part of the file" which could have been answered within 5 minutes of you asking. I'm sorry, but I feel like I wasted a chunk of my life.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Not like that.. Check the questions I am looking for two possibilities.. If the users waits too long then for file hashing itself take too long -> then upload time will take too long.. so int hat case i can just do part of chunks.. If u look at my question i have mentioned both.. "However I am facing problem when generating HASH VALUE for large files as in client side the browser Crashed." For large files only i was doing less chunks..

Comment: I'm trying to folow your answer, but with local file. When i import file from local storage, i'm getting an error, described in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691000/invalidstateerror-an-attempt-was-made-to-use-an-object-that-is-not-or-is-no-lo question