# Best way to manage sawtooth keys in the broser? (something like metamask)

Tags: ethereum, metamask, hyperledger-sawtooth

I'm facing my first sawtooth app and I'm not sure how you are supposed to handle the user's keys to sign transactions locally. The client is going to be a web app.

I was wondering if there is something like metamask for sawtooth, or even if metamask would be officially compatible with sawtooth. I've checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582064/how-can-you-sign-hyperledger-sawtooth-transactions-using-metamask-keys) and it seems to work, but with low level changes that make me wonder if that will work for long.

What is the recommended way to do this?