# How to encrypt files with AES algorithm with CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I have code to encrypt files using RC4 algorithm.
I was strongly advised to use a more reliable algorithm: AES.
From the CryptoJS documentation, I understood that it works the same way as RC4. That is, the first argument is the string to be encrypted, and the second argument is the password string.

But simply replacing the RC4 method with AES did not help and I do not know where to look for the necessary information.

Thank you!

Here is my working (for RC4) code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha512-E8QSvWZ0eCLGk4km3hxSsNmGWbLtSCSUcewDQPQWZF6pEU8GlT8a5fF32wOl1i8ftdMhssTrF/OhyGWwonTcXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div>
  <h1>encrypt/decrypt file</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Set password</li>
    <li>Pick a file</li>
    <li>Download decrypted/encrypted file</li>
  </ol>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="pass" placeholder="pass">
    <button id="encrypt">encrypt file</button>
    <button id="decrypt">decrypt file</button>
    <button id="test">test</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // support
  const download = (data, filename, type) => {
    const file = new Blob([data], {
      type: type
    });
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    a.click();

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 0);
  };
  const pickAFile = (getText = true) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'file';
      input.onchange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        if (!getText) {
          resolve(file);
        } else {
          reader.onload = (e) => resolve(e.target.result);
          reader.onerror = (e) => reject(e);
          reader.readAsText(file);
        }
      };
      input.click();
    });
  };
  const convertWordArrayToUint8Array = (wordArray) => {
    const arrayOfWords = wordArray.hasOwnProperty('words') ? wordArray.words : [];

    const length = wordArray.hasOwnProperty('sigBytes') ?
      wordArray.sigBytes :
      arrayOfWords.length * 4;

    const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(length);
    let index = 0;
    let word;
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      word = arrayOfWords[i];
      uInt8Array[index++] = word >> 24;
      uInt8Array[index++] = (word >> 16) & 0xff;
      uInt8Array[index++] = (word >> 8) & 0xff;
      uInt8Array[index++] = word & 0xff;
    }
    return uInt8Array;
  };
  // /support

  function app() {
    const passNode = document.querySelector('input#pass');
    const encryptNode = document.querySelector('#encrypt');
    const decryptNode = document.querySelector('#decrypt');

    encryptNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!passNode.value) return alert('Password input is empty! Aborting.');
      const pass = CryptoJS.SHA3(passNode.value);
      pickAFile(false).then((file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
          const wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(e.target.result);
          const encrypted = CryptoJS.RC4.encrypt(wordArray, pass).toString();
          download(encrypted, `encrypted-${file.name}`, file.type);
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      });
    });

    decryptNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!passNode.value) return alert('Password input is empty! Aborting.');
      const pass = CryptoJS.SHA3(passNode.value);
      pickAFile(false).then((file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
          try {
            const decrypted = CryptoJS.RC4.decrypt(e.target.result, pass);
            const typedArray = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(decrypted);
            download(typedArray, `decrypted-${file.name}`, file.type);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('wrong password!');
          }
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
      });
    });
  }

  if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app);
  } else {
    app();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Just to be sure: do you really want to pass the key material as a password? In this case, CryptoJS applies the OpenSSL key derivation function EVP_BytesToKey() to be compatible with OpenSSL. However, this key derivation function is deprecated and insecure. Alternatively, the key material can be passed directly as key. In the first case the IV is implicitly derived in the second case it must be explicitly generated and handled.

Comment: @Topaco, I like the second option you suggested. I'd like the maximum security available in browser JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting from RC4 to AES, consider the following:

- AES defines key sizes of 16 (AES-128), 24 (AES-192), and 32 bytes (AES-256). The larger the key, the more secure (although nowadays all variants are considered secure). In the following a 32 bytes key is used.

  The SHA3 CryptoJS implementation you apply (actually Keccak, see [Hashing/SHA-3](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#hashing)) has an output size of 64 bytes by default and therefore cannot be used directly as an AES key. Therefore I apply SHA-256 with an output size of 32 bytes for simplicity. You could also use SHA-3 and only take e.g. the first 32 bytes.

  However, the key derivation via a digest is a vulnerability. More secure is the use of a key derivation like Argon2 or PBKDF2. The latter is supported by CryptoJS and I therefore recommend to switch to PBKDF2. Since I'm focusing here on converting RC4 to AES, I'll leave that change to you.
- AES needs in CBC mode (which is used by default by CryptoJS; default padding is PKCS#7 btw) a random IV (its length is equal to the blocksize, so 16 bytes for AES). This must not be static for security reasons, but must be randomly generated (with a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)) for each encryption.

  The IV is not secret and is needed for decryption. Therefore, it is usually concatenated with the ciphertext: IV|ciphertext.

  Before decryption, the IV and ciphertext are separated based on the known length of the IV.

A possible switch from RC4 to AES that takes the above points into account is (see also the comments in the code for an explanation of the changes):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha512-E8QSvWZ0eCLGk4km3hxSsNmGWbLtSCSUcewDQPQWZF6pEU8GlT8a5fF32wOl1i8ftdMhssTrF/OhyGWwonTcXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div>
  <h1>encrypt/decrypt file</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Set password</li>
    <li>Pick a file</li>
    <li>Download decrypted/encrypted file</li>
  </ol>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="pass" placeholder="pass">
    <button id="encrypt">encrypt file</button>
    <button id="decrypt">decrypt file</button>
    <button id="test">test</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // support
  const download = (data, filename, type) => {
    const file = new Blob([data], {
      type: type
    });
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    a.click();

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 0);
  };
  const pickAFile = (getText = true) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'file';
      input.onchange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        if (!getText) {
          resolve(file);
        } else {
          reader.onload = (e) => resolve(e.target.result);
          reader.onerror = (e) => reject(e);
          reader.readAsText(file);
        }
      };
      input.click();
    });
  };
  const convertWordArrayToUint8Array = (wordArray) => {
    const arrayOfWords = wordArray.hasOwnProperty('words') ? wordArray.words : [];

    const length = wordArray.hasOwnProperty('sigBytes') ?
      wordArray.sigBytes :
      arrayOfWords.length * 4;

    const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(length);
    let index = 0;
    let word;
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      word = arrayOfWords[i];
      uInt8Array[index++] = word >> 24;
      uInt8Array[index++] = (word >> 16) & 0xff;
      uInt8Array[index++] = (word >> 8) & 0xff;
      uInt8Array[index++] = word & 0xff;
    }
    return uInt8Array;
  };
  // /support

  function app() {
    const passNode = document.querySelector('input#pass');
    const encryptNode = document.querySelector('#encrypt');
    const decryptNode = document.querySelector('#decrypt');

    encryptNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!passNode.value) return alert('Password input is empty! Aborting.');
      const key = CryptoJS.SHA256(passNode.value); // Fix 1: Derive 32 bytes key
      pickAFile(false).then((file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
          const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16); // Fix 2: Create random 16 bytes IV
          const wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(e.target.result);
          const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(wordArray, key, {iv: iv}); // Fix 3: Encrypt with AES using the above key and IV
          const ivCiphertext = iv.clone().concat(encrypted.ciphertext).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); // Fix 4: Concatenate IV and ciphertext
         download(ivCiphertext, `encrypted-${file.name}`, file.type);
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      });
    });

    decryptNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!passNode.value) return alert('Password input is empty! Aborting.');
      const key = CryptoJS.SHA256(passNode.value); // Fix 5: Derive 32 bytes key
      pickAFile(false).then((file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
          try {
            const ivCiphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(e.target.result); // Fix 6: Separate IV and ciphertext
            const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(ivCiphertext.words.slice(0, 4)); 
            const ciphertext = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(ivCiphertext.words.slice(4)); 
            const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: ciphertext}, key, {iv: iv}); // Fix 7: Decrypt
            const typedArray = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(decrypted);
            download(typedArray, `decrypted-${file.name}`, file.type);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('wrong password!');
          }
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
      });
    });
  }

  if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app);
  } else {
    app();
  }
</script>
```

---

Note that the code can still be optimized (this applies also to the RC4 variant): During encryption, the data (i.e. the concatenated IV and ciphertext) is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. Base64 is a binary-to-text encoding which increases the data size by about 33%. It is used when arbitrary binary data is to be represented as text.
However, since the data is stored as a file here, such a conversion is not really necessary (of course, there may be reasons that are not apparent from the post). Instead, the raw (i.e. the non-Base64 encoded data) can be stored, which would reduce the file size accordingly.

Comment: You just have no idea how much you helped me!
The vulnerability you wrote about, as I understand it, arises from the fact that a password hashed with `CryptoJS.SHA256` is used as a key?
I carefully studied the materials and some js libraries and came to the following conclusions:

Comment: **Why?**
In general, generating a sha256 hash for use as a key is acceptable, but for some reason it has a number of disadvantages.
So special tools were invented specifically for generating such keys.
One of the safest and best known is PBKDF2.

Comment: **How?**
I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/pbkdf2.
The call looks like this: `pbkdf2.pbkdf2Sync('password', 'salt', 1, 32, 'sha512')`.
I understand that since all the action takes place in the browser, I cannot use a dynamic salt.
I don't quite understand what the other parameters mean.
Next, I will need to substitute the result of `pbkdf2.pbkdf2Sync` into the `key` variable instead of `CryptoJS.SHA256(input.value)`. Right?

Comment: @Alexander - I don't understand why you don't use [CryptoJS#PBKDF2](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#pbkdf2) (after all, you are already using CryptoJS). The salt is analogous to the IV: it is randomly generated for each encryption; it is also not secret and is usually concatenated as well, e.g. salt|iv|ciphertext. Regarding your first question, s. [PBKDF2 vs SHA256](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/16354).

Comment: where should I get salt? I understand that I can take a static salt, but perhaps there is a better option? I generated a string from the documentation example: `df8d78f4783c03760cdabfba6c563f2b`.
`CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);`. I see that this salt is a standard hexadecimal number. What do you say if I use some sha (eg sha256) password hash as a salt? Or can you get by with a simple static salt? like: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_js_developer/kxz15v0L/

Comment: @Alexander - With regard to the salt, the approach is completely analogous to the IV: During encryption a random salt is generated. It is concatenated with the ciphertext so that it can be used for key derivation during decryption. That's all. Using a static salt, on the other hand, is insecure. If you have any further questions, please ask a new SO question. Switching to PBKDF2 is outside the scope of this post, and such things are also hard to discuss in comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557344/where-do-i-need-to-take-the-salt-for-the-pbkdf2-algorithm-if-the-program-is-runn