# Where do I need to take the salt for the PBKDF2 algorithm if the program is running in a browser?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptojs, pbkdf2

So, I have a program that requests a file, encrypts it with an AES password, and lets you download it to your computer.

https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_js_developer/kxz15v0L/

However, there is one drawback: the encryption key is a sha256 hash. I need a more reliable option - namely hashing the password through the PBKDF2 algorithm.

I figured out how to implement the use of PBKDF2 instead of sha256:

```js
const passToKey = (pass, salt = 'df8d78f4783c03760cdabfba6c563f2b') => {
  const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
    keySize: 256 / 32
    iterations: 1000
  });

  return key;
}
```

The problem is that the encrypted file needs to be decrypted after some time and possibly in a different browser. But after encryption, the salt changes and the key does not fit and it is impossible to decrypt the encrypted file back.

Q: Where do I get salt from? Is it possible to use, for example, a password hash as a salt? Or generate a random one, attach it to the beginning of the encryption, and then extract it?

Thank you!

Comment: The usual procedure is to generate a random salt during encryption, which is applied for key derivation. The decrypting side of course also needs this salt for key derivation. Since the salt is not secret, it is usually sent to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext (usually concatenated). The decrypting side can then separate the salt based on its known length and use it for key derivation.

Comment: With regard to the linked code, this means: Create a random salt (analogous to the IV) during encryption. Perform the key derivation with this salt. Generate the ciphertext with the thus determined key and IV. Concatenate salt, IV and ciphertext: salt|iv|ciphertext and send it to the decrypting side. When decrypting, separate all three parts. With the salt, the key derivation is performed. With the thus determined key and IV the ciphertext is decrypted.

Comment: The main problem is that we do not have the password source (the user entered it once, got the hash and that's it, the system deletes the form, storing the password hash inside the closure).  That is, we can store the salt used in encryption in each file, but then, when we want to decrypt the file, we will take this salt, ok, but to generate code from the cipher, we need to somehow find out the original user password to salt  its hash and use this hash as the code for the file. Let me remind you that it can take a long time between encryption and decryption and it may not be the same computer

Comment: If the password is entered only once and only the hash is available thereafter, and the salt cannot be determined at the time of password entry (as I understand your environment constraint), you could use the SHA2/3 hash as the password for PBKDF2. You would then have a SHA2/3 hashing, which is unnecessary for security, but necessary from a technical perspective.

Comment: @Topaco, Okay, I'll do that. Looks like that's all I wanted to know. You helped me a lot and saved me a lot of time. Best wishes to you!