# InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable javascript error

Tags: javascript, web-worker, local-files

I'm trying to follow this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28213834/632224

to get some files hashed in browser, but when i replace

```
"importScripts('http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js');"+
```

with something like `"importScripts('path to local copy of md5.js');"+` i'm getting error  `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable` in blob line 1.

Here is content of that blob:

```
importScripts('path to local copy of md5.js');
var md5, cryptoType;
self.onmessage = function webWorkerOnMessage(e){
    function arrayBufferToWordArray(ab) {
        var i8a = new Uint8Array(ab);
        var a = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) {
          a.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]);
        }
        return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(a, i8a.length);
    }
    if (e.data.type === "create") {
        md5 = CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create();
        postMessage({type: "create"});
    } else if (e.data.type === "update") {
        md5.update(arrayBufferToWordArray(e.data.chunk));
        postMessage({type: "update"});
    } else if (e.data.type === "finish") {
        postMessage({type: "finish", hash: ""+md5.finalize()});
    }
}
```

UPDATE: FF throws error from question title, when i try code in chrome, i'm getting `Uncaught [object DOMException]` error.

I have tried different ways to enter path, both windows and linux style, tried both relative and full path, but it's not working.

I guess, for some reason, code can't find file on disk, but don't know why.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried using the file syntax: `file:///local.js`?

Comment: That will do it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the file protocol: `file:///local.js`