# How to test if Fetch API is available in Web Worker from main frame

Tags: javascript, web-worker, fetch-api

I'm using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) when available in a browser by simply testing the `window.fetch`.

However in the case of Safari 10, `fetch` is available in the main frame, which instantiate a web worker but it is not available in the web worker frame.

Is there a way to test if a top level function is available in a web worker from the main frame ?

Ideally, we could have a reference of the web worker instance and test if a property is available on the `self` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to test if a top level function is available in a web worker from the main frame ?

Not synchronously.

However, in many browsers you can create a Web Worker instance from a blob or data-uri. You could create a web worker that runs a `typeof` test and sends the result back as a message. See [How to create a Web Worker from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343913/how-to-create-a-web-worker-from-a-string) for more information.

I'd suggest that this may be one of those rare instances where browser version detection is more appropriate.