# Create js function from string without eval and new Function()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any alternative solution to create js-function from string var, except `eval()` and `Function constructor`
I'm not allowed to use this both methods for security reason.

I know solution when you create DOM element with js code and add to page, but it's absolutely dirty hack.
Thank you very much for help.

====

**ADD**

I received json-data with string like "a === b", "!a", "(a && b) || c" and so on... (hundreds of combinations). Need to create and return function which can do this compare function.

Something

```
var test = function ('a === b') {
  //some code without eval and new Function()
}
// in console
test('aa', 'bb') // return false
```

Comment: If you have access to file system, then create a new file, add the code inside it and load the JS file dynamically.

Comment: Whats the usecase?

Comment: @VedranMaricevic cool idea but i haven't access

Comment: Can you use WebWorkers?

Comment: @Jonasw I received json-data with string like "a ===  b", "!a", "(a && b) || c" and so on... (hundreds of combinations). Need to create and return function which can do this compare function

Comment: can you update Q with sample ip and op

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use this both methods for security reason" — That's because of the inherent risks in turning strings into executable code, not because of those specific methods.

Comment: If it is for security reason, then webworkers can be an option as they create some sandbox. This answer can help you I guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372280/2745879

Comment: @atomrc Maybe yes I don't know. Try to read your link

Comment: @SagarV I don't understand your answer. Can you write a little bit more information. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't made an answer

Comment: @Quentin yep, I understand why. It's only information that I know this solution. Thanks

Comment: @SagarV What is ip and op? Sorry English is not my native language

Comment: input and output

Comment: If your code runs on Node, you can use this alternative that uses node's VM that seems pretty good https://github.com/hacksparrow/safe-eval

Comment: @SagarV edit Q and add code

Comment: @atomrc no :( in browser

Comment: Then the only option I can think of is WebWorkers then. I am not aware of any other ways to do that. It seems overkill for what you want to do though!

Comment: Why not just make a simple parser for it

Comment: What exactly prevents you from ("disallows") using `eval` and `Function`? This seems to be the perfect use case.

Comment: I agree with you. That's why I used to WebWorkers. WebWorkers have special content security policy, so in my case it was the best way to fix the problem and I can use new Function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks all of you for interesting answers.

So, I had read and tried to use all methods, that you suggested me.
All of them it’s eval() even you wont be used eval in your code.
In my project I fixed problem using WebWorkers. This technologi has a lot benefits, please read article in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

But, I have to use "new Function" for this method.

So correct answer is:

**You cannot create function from string without eval and new Function()**.

The only way it’s to write your own simple parser for that.

Thanks **@brianxautumn**