# Cannot create web worker from string in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-worker

Cannot create inline web workers using BLOB-URL in IE11. 
Works fine in Edge, Firefox, Chrome. (All browsers are up-to-date.)

For example below JavaScript code fails to create web worker.

```
try{
 var blob = new Blob(["(" + function1.toString() + ")(" + parametersJSON + ")"], {type: 'application/javascript'}); 
 var x = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
 var worker = new Worker(x);
} catch(err){
 console.log(err);// displays "invalid function" in IE11.
}
```

Any help?

Is there any other alternative? to achieve the goal of creating a web worker from a string without using the external file? (Should work in InternetExplorer 11+)

Full code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Worker Test</title>
        <script>

            function function1(parametersJSON){

                console.log(parametersJSON.testKey1);
            }
            try{
                var parametersJSON = {'testKey1':'foo','testKey2':'bar'};
                var parametersJSONString = JSON.stringify(parametersJSON);
                var blob = new Blob(["(" + function1.toString() + ")(" + parametersJSONString + ")"], {type: 'application/javascript'}); 
                var x = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
                var worker = new Worker(x);
            } catch(err){
                console.log(err);// displays "invalid function" in IE11.
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please inform us, What are the values stored in function1.toString() and parametersJSON. After that we can make a test with your code to check for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFTI have updated the question with complete code which does not work in IE 11.

Comment: I try to make a several tests and based on the results, I find that in IE we need to use External file to create web worker. Without that IE is producing the error. So at present, It looks like it is not possible to create web worker in IE without using an external file.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT There is a workaround for IE here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343913/how-to-create-a-web-worker-from-a-string