# Execute a javascript function in a parallel unit

Tags: javascript, node.js, worker

The question is formalized as this.

**Can we call a non-pure function in another thread in javascript and get a Promise?**

One possible implementation of this feature is.

`function executeAsync(f: function, ...args);`

```
1. Javascript runtime spawns 1 parallel unit (thread, coroutine, etc).

2. Javascript runtime executes the function f in parallel. (Ignore data race issue, maybe add mutex later)

3. After the parallel unit has done its job. Remove the parallel unit from the pool and resolve the Promise. (put callback into the callback queue)
```

Please comment if you still have any doubt. Thanks

**FOR REFERENCES**

The code below I implemented serves the similar purpose but it doesn't work for **non-pure function**
It uses `safe-eval` node module that evaluates a string and convert to javascript function

```
const {isMainThread, Worker, workerData, parentPort} = require("worker_threads");
const {safeEval} = require("safe-eval");
if (isMainThread) {
  // functionObject must be pure function
  module.exports = {executeAsync: function(functionObject = function(...paramsObject) {return undefined;}, ...paramsObject) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const worker = new Worker(__filename, {
        workerData: {
          functionString: functionObject.toString(),
          argumentsObject: paramsObject,
        }
      });
      worker.on("message", resolve);
      worker.on("error", reject);
      worker.on("exit", function(functionObject) {
        if (functionObject != 0) {
          reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with code ${functionObject}`));
        }
      });
    });
  }};
} else {
  const {functionString, argumentsObject} = workerData;
  const functionObject = safeEval(functionString);
  parentPort.postMessage(functionObject(...argumentsObject));
}
```

Comment: You can execute function at the same moment you express that - `Immediately invoked function expression`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: worker_threads is useful for cpu-bound tasks, in your scenario, async/await would be ok.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov i want to execute that function in a different thread and receive a promise

Comment: But there is no different thread. As @HengqiChen said you should use async/await.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Can you provide me a sample code for using `async`, `await` to serve that purpose? I am really understand why `async` `await` related to this

Comment: `async function add(a,b) { return new Promise(resolve => resolve(a*b))}`

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov It does not work the way it's like in C++. There still single threaded

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov please read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Answer (score 1):

> One particular approach to this in JavaScript is putting the function into a executeAsync function, it returns a promise for us to access it later.

This is a common misconception. Promises don't make something that's synchronous asynchronous. They're just a standardized way to **observe** something that's **already** asynchronous. The only asynchronous behavior they themselves provide is that when you register a handler via `.then` (or `.catch` or `.finally`), you're guaranteed that that handler will be called asynchronously, not synchronously, even if the promise is already settled. And even then, it's *asynchronous*, not *parallel*. The callback happens on the same thread, just later.

The only way¹ to get truly parallel processing in browser-based JavaScript is to use [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), which Node.js's workers are modelled on. As you've said, that *mostly* means you have to have a separate file for the code that will run in the worker, although [it is possible to use a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343913/how-to-create-a-web-worker-from-a-string).

---

¹ "only way" - well, technically separate independent tabs may end up running in different threads, but only if they are created completely independently. If one tab opens another, they'll share the same thread, since they each have a reference to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first part does not directly target the question. "The only way¹ to get truly parallel processing in browser-based JavaScript is to use web workers" - thanks

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn - No, the first part targets a common misconception expressed in the question, as I said above.

Comment: Thanks, it might be due to ambiguity I made in the question