# Multiple state changes in event listener, how to NOT batch the DOM updates?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a component to test the performance of different algorithms. The algorithms return the ms they took to run and this is want I want to display. The "fastAlgorithm" takes about half a second, and the "slowAlgorithm" takes around 5 seconds.

My problem is that the UI is not re-rendered with the result until both algorithms have finished. I would like to display the result for the fast algorithm as soon as it finishes, and the slow algorithm when that one finishes.

I've read about how React batches updates before re-rendering, but is there someway to change this behavior? Or is there a better way to organize my component/s to achieve what I want?

I'm using react 16.13.1

Here is my component:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { fastAlgorithm, slowAlgorithm } from '../utils/algorithms'

const PerformanceTest = () => {

  const [slowResult, setSlowResult] = useState(false)
  const [fastResult, setFastResult] = useState(false)

  const testPerformance = async () => {
    fastAlgorithm().then(result => {
      setFastResult(result)
    })
    slowAlgorithm().then(result => {
      setSlowResult(result)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={testPerformance}>Run test!</button>
      <div>{fastResult}</div>
      <div>{slowResult}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PerformanceTest
```

I read somewhere that ReactDOM.flushSync() would trigger the re-rendering on each state change, but it did not make any difference. This is what I tried:

```
const testPerformance = async () => {
  ReactDOM.flushSync(() =>
    fastAlgorithm().then(result => {
      setFastResult(result)
    })
  )
  ReactDOM.flushSync(() => 
    slowAlgorithm().then(result => {
      setSlowResult(result)
    })
  )
}
```

And also this:

```
const testPerformance = async () => {
  fastAlgorithm().then(result => {
    ReactDOM.flushSync(() =>
      setFastResult(result)
    )
  })
  slowAlgorithm().then(result => {
    ReactDOM.flushSync(() =>
      setSlowResult(result)
    )
  })
}
```

I also tried restructuring the algorithms so they didn't use Promises and tried this, with no luck:

```
 const testPerformance = () => {
   setFastResult(fastAlgorithm())
   setSlowResult(slowAlgorithm())
 }
```

**Edit**

As **Sujoy Saha** suggested in a comment below, I replaced my algorithms with simple ones using setTimeout(), and everything works as expected. "Fast" is displayed first and then two seconds later "Slow" is displayed.

However, if I do something like the code below it doesn't work. Both "Fast" and "Slow" shows up when the slower function finishes... Does anyone know exactly when/how the batch rendering in React happens, and how to avoid it?

```
export const slowAlgorithm  = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const array = []
    for(let i = 0; i < 9000; i++) {
      for(let y = 0; y < 9000; y++) {
        array.push(y);
      }
    }
    resolve('slow')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial **PerfomanceTest** component is correct. The component will re-render for the each state change. I think issue is in your algorithm. Please let us know how did you returned promise there.
Follow below code snippet for your reference.

```
export const fastAlgorithm  = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('fast')
    }, 1000)
  })
}

export const slowAlgorithm  = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('slow')
    }, 3000)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I replaced my algorithms with your code, and everything works as expected. "Fast" is displayed first and then two seconds later "Slow" is displayed. However, if I remove the setTimeout() function and instead does something like below it doesn't work. Both "Fast" and "Slow" shows up when the slower function finishes... 

`export const slowAlgorithm  = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const array = []

    for(let i = 0; i < 9000; i++) {
      for(let y = 0; y < 9000; y++) {
        array.push(y);
      }
    }

    resolve('slow')

  })
}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your algorithms synchronously on the main thread? If so, that's probably what's blocking React from re-rendering. You may need to move them to [worker threads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).

The below is loosely based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372280), minus all the compatibility stuff (assuming you don't need IE support):

```js
// `args` must contain all dependencies for the function.
const asyncify = (fn) => {
    return (...args) => {
        const workerStr =
            `const fn = ${fn.toString()}

            self.onmessage = ({ data: args }) => {
                self.postMessage(fn(...args))
            }`

        const blob = new Blob([workerStr], { type: 'application/javascript' })

        const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob))

        let abort = () => {}

        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            worker.onmessage = (result) => {
                resolve(result.data)
                worker.terminate()
            }

            worker.onerror = (err) => {
                reject(err)
                worker.terminate()
            }

            // In case we need it for cleanup later.
            // Provide either a default value to resolve to
            // or an Error object to throw
            abort = (value) => {
                if (value instanceof Error) reject(value)
                else resolve(value)
                worker.terminate()
            }
        })

        worker.postMessage(args)

        return Object.assign(promise, { abort })
    }
}

const multiplySlowly = (x, y) => {
    const start = Date.now()

    const arr = [...new Array(x)].fill([...new Array(y)])

    return {
        x,
        y,
        result: arr.flat().length,
        timeElapsed: Date.now() - start,
    }
}

const multiplySlowlyAsync = asyncify(multiplySlowly)

// rendering not blocked - just pretend this is React
const render = (x) => document.write(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(x, null, 4)}</pre>`)

multiplySlowlyAsync(999, 9999).then(render)

multiplySlowlyAsync(15, 25).then(render)
```

Note that `fn` is effectively being `eval`ed in the context of the worker thread here, so you need to make sure the code is trusted. Presumably it is, given that you're already happy to run it on the main thread.

For completeness, here's a TypeScript version:

```ts
type AbortFn<T> = (value: T | Error) => void

export type AbortablePromise<T> = Promise<T> & {
    abort: AbortFn<T>
}

// `args` must contain all dependencies for the function.
export const asyncify = <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T) => {
    return (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
        const workerStr =
            `const fn = ${fn.toString()}

            self.onmessage = ({ data: args }) => {
                self.postMessage(fn(...args))
            }`

        const blob = new Blob([workerStr], { type: 'application/javascript' })

        const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob))

        let abort = (() => {}) as AbortFn<ReturnType<T>>

        const promise = new Promise<ReturnType<T>>((resolve, reject) => {
            worker.onmessage = (result) => {
                resolve(result.data)
                worker.terminate()
            }

            worker.onerror = (err) => {
                reject(err)
                worker.terminate()
            }

            // In case we need it for cleanup later.
            // Provide either a default value to resolve to
            // or an Error object to throw
            abort = (value: ReturnType<T> | Error) => {
                if (value instanceof Error) reject(value)
                else resolve(value)

                worker.terminate()
            }
        })

        worker.postMessage(args)

        return Object.assign(promise, { abort }) as AbortablePromise<
            ReturnType<T>
        >
    }
}
```