# Is it possible to create shared worker from a string and to use it without sharing the worker URL?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Probably this is not possible but I would be glad to hear about alternatives.

I have a large JS script which I want to run in a `SharedWorker`, but without uploading it to a server before running (it's included in a library which I want to distribute).
With `Dedicated Worker` I can simply make a `Blob`. But the `Blob` URL is unique and also his lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the window that creates it.

What I need is a way to create `SharedWorker` from a `string` but this worker should have a URL that any other page should be able to compute exactly. `Base64` strings are limited in size, so my question is if there are any alternatives to it.

Comment: `(it's included in a library which I want to distribute).`,  so some how the client has access to this, if so, why not just load directly into a service worker?.

Comment: It wouldn't be accessible by a `cdn`, but developers would be able to install it (via `npm`)

Comment: You're looking for a way to start a local server in the browser using SharedWorker, and make it persist after the window closes?

Comment: In that case, I would say a Blob URL is the way,.. But what you could do is create a very small WebWorker with this option, and then send the large code bit via `PostMessage` to the webworker.

Comment: @keith thanks. Would you like to write it as an answer so I would be able to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to create a WebWorker from a string, and this string could be very large.  Instead of creating a very large data URI, or Blob URL.  You could use that option to bootstrap a WebWorker first.  Inside the WebWorker you could then wait for a message sent via postMessage that contained the large code to execute.

One thing to note:  you are going to require the webWorker to then `new Function` or `eval` the code, so be aware of any XSS attack vectors.  From what you are describing this sounds like it's not an issue, but I thought it might be worth pointing out.

Also just found -> [How to create a Web Worker from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343913/how-to-create-a-web-worker-from-a-string)  That also has a fallback that uses `eval` so that might also help.