# Run function in the same JavaScript file as a worker

Tags: javascript, html, worker

I'm working on a browser JavaScript project that requires multi-threading for efficiency. I understand web workers are the only possible way to achieve this. I've taken a look but have ran into limitations with the way workers work by default, and would like to know the most optimal way to address them.

```
var worker = new Worker("myscript.js")
```

There are two problems. First I don't want my worker to be a different js file, I want it to just run a locally defined function... this wouldn't be a big deal if it weren't for the second issue: The stupidly excessive security systems of most browsers throw an error similar to CORS when using a local JS file, Firefox thinks `index.html` is trying to illegally access the content of the worker script... my project is meant to work when unpacked and ran locally in addition to being hosted online, I specifically design them to not require hosting on a web server just for basic functionality to work.

So far I found partial answers that suggest you can achieve this using a blob. They are however very convoluted, in that they show how to create a blob for type text / JavaScript but not how to put my locally defined function into it. Thus my question is: How do I do what I've exemplified below in a single JS file, in the simplest form that's unlikely to ever trigger any browser security limitations even when the project is ran locally?

```
function worker_func() {
    console.log("Works!")
}

var blob = new Blob()
blob.load_as_text(worker_func)
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
var worker = new Worker(url)
```

Extra info: The function ran by the worker is part of an instanced class that spawns it. It would thus be ideal to know how do this in a way that preserves `this`, eg: `worker_func.bind(this)` when done normally. I shouldn't need to give the worker function any parameters if it knows how to access the class instance it's related to.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343913/how-to-create-a-web-worker-from-a-string

Comment: "*how to put my locally defined function into it?*" - you don't. You could use `worker_func.toString()` to get the function *code* as a string, but ultimately you will also need some boilerplate code to connect the function calls to events, and also you'll need to put all dependencies of the function in the worker code as well. So really you should put them in a string or separate `<script>` - neither of which has to be an external file - instead of using a function declaration that is never invoked anyway. You cannot "move" a function object into the worker, it's a separate environment.

Comment: "*The function ran by the worker is part of an instanced class that spawns it. It would thus be ideal to know how do this in a way that preserves `this`*" - this is impossible. You can interact with the worker only via events, and need to serialise all data that is passed. The worker is a completely separate environment, running its own code and instantiating its own objects and functions, you can only *communicate* with it. You cannot access objects from the other environment.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. In this case it does seem better to make my function a string from the beginning. That linked question helps a little, even if it still looks very convoluted... also it suggests argument on whether some browsers will allow it for security, wonder what decision had been reached on the matter and if an irrevocable decision exists so there's no risk that it suddenly stops working at a later date.

Comment: Local files (`file://...`) are not trusted, for good reason. You can serve your code from a simple local server if you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Web workers without a separate Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408406/web-workers-without-a-separate-javascript-file)

This seems to provide a full answer which actually works on Firefox! I'm still unsure whether all browsers will allow it though, do any of the mainstream ones block that for security's sake? Also let me know if the solution there can be otherwise improved. For now I can confirm the following executes without errors at least in FF:

```
var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob([ "(", function() {
    console.log("Works!");
}.toString(), ")()" ], { type: 'application/javascript' } ))

var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
```