# jCarousel Lite not working when using Transitional Doctype in the HTML

Tags: jquery, html, jcarousellite

I am using jCarousel Lite for a slider from this [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/)

But when i place this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

it stops working.How can be jCarousel Lite working with Transitional Doctype??Any help please.

Comment: The Doctype should trigger Standards mode. The Doctype used on the jCarousel Lite demo also uses a Doctype that triggers standards mode. It shouldn't cause it to break.

Comment: Define "stops working". What errors do you get?

Comment: @Quentin no error is getting.but the slider is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process to troubleshoot:

- Convert the working JCarousel HTML page to a [data URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238890/1113772)
- Add that data URL to the XHTML page using an `object` element:

  ```
  <object type="text/html" data="data:text/html;charset=utf-8;,%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3C%2Fhead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cp%3EXHTML%20is%20the%20best%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E"></object>
  ```
- If it works, then it is a [markup generation issue](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox:3.0_DOM_Case_Sensitivity)
- If not, then it is a browser specific issue