# Create .webarchive in Windows without Safari?

Tags: safari, webkit, webarchive

Is there any way to convert a web site to to Safari's .webarchive using Windows and without using Safari?

I know it's an odd request, but I need to create .webarchive files and load them into a UIWebView, and (for various reasons beyond my control) using Safari or Mac is not an option.

I was thinking that Webkit may have some available methods for it, but wasn't having much luck.

Comment: [WebCore](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/loader/archive) source is available if a port is required.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that but was hoping there would be a less complicated solution than porting or modifying the WebKit source.

Comment: As an alternative, [converting HTML pages to dataURIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238890/) would be a cross-browser solution.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Wasn't totally idea, since filesizes can balloon pretty quickly, but it did the trick. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Here are alternatives from unrelated questions:

- [Converting HTML pages to dataURIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238890/)
- [Using HTML5 Canvas to take Screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/)