# Using icon font with the browser's Notifications API

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, notifications, glyphicons

I am planning on adding the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API) functionality to a web app I am building.

I took a look at the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification#Example) from the MDN site:

```
function spawnNotification(theBody, theIcon, theTitle) {
    var options = {
        body: theBody,
        icon: theIcon
    };
    var n = new Notification(theTitle, options);
}
```

It allows the URL of an image (`icon`) to be specified as the icon in the notification popup box.  Since I am using [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and [glyphicons](/questions/tagged/glyphicons), is there a way that I can use one of the images from the icon font as the icon for the notification?

Answer (score 0):

I tried wrapping up the html into a data URI using the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239272/1575353) but that didn't appear to work so it seems that there is no option using the Notifications API.

You could consider using the [Bootstrap Notify plugin](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/) instead, which appears to support [a class for a font icon in the options](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/#documentation-options).