# How to avoid MalformedURLException when URL is "data:text/html"?

Tags: android, url, webview, malformedurlexception

In my WebView-based app, when the app accesses http://mobile.nytimes.com/ my WebViewClient receives 6-7 onPageFinished(), the first 3-4 with [WebView.getUrl(](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl())) returning the original URL (http://mobile.nytimes.com/) but then it returns "data:text/html" for the rest.

Apparently, [data:text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239272/2597758) is a [valid URI](http://lifehacker.com/5980134/turn-any-browser-window-into-a-quick-edit-notepad). Also see https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-scheme .

However, in my code, I need to instantiate a URL from WebView's url like this:

```
new URL(myWebView.getUrl());
```

and unfortunately this throws a  MalformedURLException when WebView.getUrl() returns 'data:text/html'.

Is there a way to convert the 'data:text/html' string to a valid URL string so that `new URL()` will not throw the **MalformedURLException**?

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote data: is a valid URI not an URL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: What about http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-scheme ? Also, if it's not a valid URL, why does `WebView.getUrl()` return it?