# Add to home function

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdk, html, homescreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I create a shortcut on desktop in iOS through an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577889/how-could-i-create-a-shortcut-on-desktop-in-ios-through-an-app)

I want to know if it's possible with the iOS API to put a web page on the home screen (in Objective-C). A specific event to catch ? A "magic" function ? :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't think so, but if you're already showing them a web view in Safari, you could do something like http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen to guide them through the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, apps can not do anything outside their sandbox.

As the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836925/iphone-sdk-add-a-add-to-home-screen-button-in-a-uiwebview) explains, you can launch your page you want to save in Safari and provide users with instructions to save the page from there, then use a url to switch apps back to your app from Safari afterwards, but you can't add a webapp to the springboard from your app itself