# Adding a button to user home screen

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to add button into user homescreen. Let's assume I have an app, when user do something with app I want to add a button into user homescreen. I'm thinking about something similar to "Add to Home Screen" from Safari app.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. It's a simple matter of designing and implementing the feature. However, your question is far, far too broad for this forum.

Comment: You can't do it natively, but apparently you can (or formerly could) do it using deep linking. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28042152/77567). It is far from simple, but the question is not too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add web link icon on home screen, and no way you can add some buttons with custom actions on home screen. Every "button" is application or link icon and nothing more

Comment: Could you please explain how to add web link(with custom icon) to home screen?

Comment: I think you need to look into https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/sharing-and-actions/